# ExtJS datefield unclickable

Tags: eclipse, jquery, extjs, tomcat7

My JSP code wont select the date and also it wont show the data of my combo box. I dont what is the problem. When I let my code run on another pc, it is working fine. I am using eclipse juno, tomcat 7, jquery and extjs.. Please help..

[image: My JSP code wont select the date and also it wont show the data of my combo box. I am using eclipse juno, tomcat 7, jquery and extjs.. Please help..]

this is my code for my JSP.

```
var genres = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields: ['id', 'genre'],
        data : [['1','Comedy'],['2','Drama'],['3','Action']]
    });



    var movie_form = new Ext.FormPanel({
        url: 'localhost:8080',
        renderTo: document.body,
        frame: true,
        title: 'Movie Information Form',
        width: 250,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Title',
            name: 'title',
            allowBlank: false
        },{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Director',
            name: 'director',
            vtype: 'name'
        },{
            xtype: 'datefield',
            fieldLabel: 'Released',
            name: 'released',
            disabledDays: [0]
        },{
            xtype: 'radio',
            fieldLabel: 'Filmed In',
            name: 'filmed_in',
            boxLabel: 'Color'
        },{
            xtype: 'radio',
            hideLabel: false,
            labelSeparator: '',
            name: 'filmed_in',
            boxLabel: 'Black and White' 
        },{
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            fieldLabel: 'Bad Movie',
            name: 'badmovie'
        },{
            xtype: 'combo',
            name: 'genre',
            fieldLabel: 'Genre',
            mode: 'local',
            store: genres,
            displayField:'genre',
            width: 120

        }]
```

Comment: My first thought is: *Caching*. If it works on another PC.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that you are using some version of IE.  Since it is localhost you are probably getting the intranet compatibility mode downgrading your version of IE to something else when Extjs is detecting it either correctly or incorrectly.

Put the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` tag at the top of your page to force the browser to render the same way it would to someone over the regular internet and force Whoever is looking at it to be using standards mode.

Also, make sure the doctype tag at the top of your pages is:

```
<!doctype html>
```